# use dfs algo for List collection in java;

Tags: data-structures, collections

I have List Of object of Element class where Element's object are like:

---

1.element1{
name : "riya",
child: false,
parentName :null
},

---

2.element2{
name : "kiya",
child: true,
parentName :"riya"
},

---

3.element3{
name : "veera",
child: false,
parentName :null
},

---

4.element1{
name : "sanam",
child: true,
parentName :"kiya"
}

---

Parent object are those whose child attribute have false value, while child object are those whose child attribute are true and parent name is described in parentName attribute.
How can i sort this List so that child always followed by their parent.